# Can i use MapView without using MapKit framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, mapkit

Without coding a Map View, if I want to put the altitude and the longitude and pin for a place, will I work it to show on the Maps Application in the iPhone?

Comment: without any code you can just show pin on current location

Comment: I don't know how yet, but thank you for telling me I can :)

Comment: you have to manually(programmatically) provide the latitude and longitude to show any specific location on mapview

Comment: I want to show it in the Maps Application in the iPhone, can I or can't? I got from @Muhammad Adnan that I can, I still didn't look for it..

Comment: @Roa By setting show current location to yes in storyboard you can get map of current location with pin . Not specific location

Comment: Do have an example for that, if you please?